# Beyond Compare as a Diff tool with Git - How to command line switch like: /expandall

Tags: git, diff, beyondcompare3

My git global config C:\Users\.gitconfig looks like:

```
[diff]
tool = bc3

[difftool "bc3"]
path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe
cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

I am using Windows 7 x64 OS. I have Beyond Compare Pro 3.3.5 version.

I want to pass one or more arguments when calling BCompare.exe 
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe\ /expandall" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"

git difftool --dir-diff dev master
```

I want to do a directory compare between a dev and master branches and to expand all folders within Beyond Compare tool. This should do the same as a corresponding button in Beyond Compare GUI: Expand All which expands all folders in left and right pane.

I need to possibly pass 2 arguments: /solo /expandall

Thanks,
Rad

Comment: Have you already checked this page? http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows

Comment: Yes. It doesn't talk about incorporating switches. My compares work, but I would like some extra functionality that switches provide.

Comment: FYI ignore file structure might do better as default behaviour in bc as opposed to expand all - it allows jumping between files using ctrl-m and ctrl-shift-m, while not being constrained by a single folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the form `-expandall` instead of `/expandall`, and note that `-solo` is **required** (explanation below).

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"E:/PortApps/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe\" -expandall -solo \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

The above works for me with Beyond Compare 3.3.8 (Standard Edition) and Git For Windows 1.8.4 (msysgit), on Windows XP SP3 (x86 32-bit).

### Notes

1. I found the `path` setting wasn't necessary if I provided `cmd`.
2. You *may* need to use `BCompare.exe` instead of `bcomp.exe`, according to [BC tech support](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=12494&highlight=bcomp) ... but I found it worked fine either way.

### Solo explained

The `-solo` option makes the comparison open in a new window. `difftool` will then wait for you to close it before deleting the temp files being compared.

Without this option, if you already have a Beyond Compare window open, the comparison will appear in a new tab there. This seems convenient but won't actually work, because `difftool` will have immediately deleted the files to be compared, since your invocation of `bcomp.exe` merely delegated the task to the already-running app and then exited.

Comment: Great that worked. Thanks. I am using VS 2013 with Git support and I can copy CommitID and copy it to my powershell posh-git and compare like this:
git difftool --dir-diff master 173dc827230751ef2cf0dcaae8229722506968ba or 
git difftool --dir-diff dev master